# How to get a variable in php file from js?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

How to pass a variable from js file to php file.i want variable from checker.js
to test.php

```
function SendData(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: "id=" + id,
        cashe: false,
        success: function(response){
            alert("Record successfully updated")
        }
    })
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    SendData(10)
})
```

test.php file

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="checker.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "how to get a variable in php file from js?" — Err… see the code in your question? Like that.

Comment: what happens when change `alert("Record successfully updated")` to `alert(response)` ? You haven't provided very much information to know what works or doesn't. Your code shown should work if path to server file is correct

Comment: @user1783058 — How can you tell? You aren't doing anything with the output in your JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see what is logged in your console:

```
function SendData(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: "id=" + id,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    SendData(10)
});
```

I am almost certain something is being returned by the server, you're just not looking for it.

If you want to retrieve your ID, you could change your php to:

```
<?php
var_dump(json_encode($_POST));
?>
```

and your js to:

```
function SendData(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: "id=" + id,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            var id = JSON.parse(response).id;
            //do something with id
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    SendData(10)
});
```

Comment: array(1) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "88"
} there is! and how then to get this id?

Comment: @user1783058 I have added how to retrieve the id.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error (or unknown key) in `SendData` function. Change `cashe` into `cache`.

And you can't see what the PHP has code written. `alert(response);`

If you want to replace the content of the index.html to the response of the test.php use:

```
function SendData(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        data: "id=" + id,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            $("body").html(response);
        }
    })
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    SendData(10)
})
```

Comment: That's not **technically** a syntax error. I assumed jQuery ignored unknown keys in the object passed?

Comment: agree with typo but that shouldn't break the code eiether

Comment: Okay, but how do I know then that in a post array? me in that file to execute the query to the database of test.php

Comment: Do you want to see the executed PHP response on the whole page?

Comment: @Asad Ya but by default cache is set to true so it could break expected behaviour